# GET: displaying same values of textbox after page submit

Tags: php, html

I have a form tag with method="get"and action="" . now I want to get all my textbox values as it is after page submit. how to do it?

Comment: All values will be in the ```$_GET```-array. You can use ```foreach``` to iterate over the array

Comment: Can you please post your code???

Answer (score 0):

You can access the input elements values using `$_GET['element_name'];`

For eg:

`<input type="text" name="textbox_1">` in your case can be accessed by

`<?php $_GET['textbox_1']; ?>`

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).